# LibGDX Animation Tool

Tags: animation, libgdx

I know that there is a tool named Spine, but it seems a bit expensive for me, are there any alternative tools for animating sprites in LibGDX? I've tried looking on the internet, but everything just points to Spine.

Comment: I don't think so...that's why Spine's Kickstarter was so successful. I remember reading that the old iPhone game Zombieville USA was made using skeletal animation, but they used a 3D package to do it and accomplished something similar to sprite batching by scaling parts of the mesh to zero through the use of bones. So if you have immense amounts of time, you could do something like that in Blender. Suppose you consider your time worth $10 an hour. You will spend orders of magnitude more than six hours devising your own solution.

Comment: Well it sounds too complicated for me and the process of getting this solution to work would be bigger than the rest of the game. Anyway, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 3):

I know two free analogues
[DragonBones](http://dragonbones.github.io/) free and easy tool, but use flash, so requared Flash Professional CS 5.5 or later;

[Spriter](http://www.brashmonkey.com/spriter.htm) non pro version is free, but isn't so easy.

Comment: I think he is looking for a tool which allows him to create such an sprite sheet which is used for a 2D animation. He is not looking for an example how to use a sprite sheet or sprite animation

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm sorry, I updated my answer.